# SCTransform Warning: in theta.ml(y = y, mu = fit$fitted) : iteration limit reached

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, sctransform

Running SCTransform on my seurat object produces the warning:

```
Warning in theta.ml(y = y, mu = fit$fitted) : iteration limit reached
```

What does this warning mean? Can I trust the output?

SCTransform runs through the data producing this warning until the progress bar reaches 100%. The resulting seurat object **does** have an SCT assay and I have successfully done downstream analysis with it. I am concerned that my SCTransform has not successfully done what it is supposed to do. Is there a way to cross-check?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation can be found in link posted by **ATpoint** in his comment:

> I get at least 10 posts on GitHub, GitMemory and Biostars just on the top page.
>
> - https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/1378
> - https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/2578
> - https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/1378
> - https://www.biostars.org/p/450394/

The first author of the SCTransform paper, Christoph Hafemeister had posted this answer in a similar query on the satijalab GitHub page https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/1378

"These warnings are related to the estimation of the theta parameter of the Negative Binomial regression model used to describe the molecule count distribution of each gene. When a gene has very few non-zero observations estimation of that parameter is not reliable and that's what the message indicates. This is not a problem, since the estimated theta parameters are not used directly for normalization but are regularized (sharing information across genes and thus lowering uncertainty)."